# Retrieve generated keys from multiple queries in single Spring JDBC Update

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc, sql-insert

I am using a single Spring JDBC update to make an update to two tables in my Postgres database. My SQL query is as follows:

```
UPDATE accounts SET last_transaction_amount = :transaction_amount WHERE acct_num = :acct_num; INSERT INTO transactions (transaction_amout) VALUES (:transaction_amount);
```

Using `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate#update`, I have no issue executing this query and achieving the expected results.

The `transactions` table generates a sequential transaction identifier, and I want to return this to my application.

I've tried passing a `GeneratedKeyHolder` in the `update` call. This is returning the error "A result was returned when none was expected". [Docs link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html#update-java.lang.String-org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.SqlParameterSource-org.springframework.jdbc.support.KeyHolder-).

I've tried passing a `GeneratedKeyHolder` and array of column names (`new String[] {"transaction_id"}`). This is returning the error that the column doesn't exist. Note this method call does work to return the transaction id when I only pass the `INSERT` query without the preceding `UPDATE` query. [Docs link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html#update-java.lang.String-org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.SqlParameterSource-org.springframework.jdbc.support.KeyHolder-java.lang.String:A-).

How can I retrieve the generated key? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be looking for the `RETURNING` clause. Assuming that the serial number is called `transaction_id`:

```
INSERT INTO transactions (transaction_amout) 
VALUES (:transaction_amount)
RETURNING transaction_id;
```

Comment: This doesn't change the behavior of the `update` call.